# Coldfusion Nondescript Error Message

Tags: excel, csv, coldfusion

1. I have a coldfusion application that queries an oracle database for some data, converts the query into a CSV variable via a function creaeted by Ben Nadel, and is supposed to use a  tag to then convert the csv value into an excel spreadsheet. However it is giving me the following error:

   "The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
   Error Occurred While Processing Request
   3

   The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/APPS/CapDB/generate_extract.cfm: line 312"

Here is the section of code it is referencing:

```
    <cfspreadsheet action="Write" filename="C:\inetpub\apps\capdb\files\extract.xls" format="csv" name="strOutput"  overwrite="true">
```

I've tried sending it different csv variables, even one created by Ben Nadel to work specifically with his custom function and the cfspreadsheet tag. The only thing that changes with the error when I use different csv variables is what number is displayed. I've seen 3 and 35 so far. Has anyone ever encountered an error like this before?

Comment: Look at the stack trace and check the CF error logs for more details about the error.

Comment: I feel like an idiot just realized that I didn't have debugging enabled on the machine I was working on. Going to investigate further and see what I find, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Why can't you simply create the spreadsheet from the query directly?